# Clojure: ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure

I've started learning clojure and I managed to get a few of the problems on Project Euler worked out but for whatever reason I've had a tough time with [this](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4) one.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1756608) is the code I have written for it. It looks to run fine until it gets to the second outer loop. Then it fails and the error message looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX6w5.jpg). I did some googling for this error and it seems to be about having extra parens but I'm not seeing where they are in my code. Alas I've probably just overlooked something simple.

Also if there are any bad coding conventions in there please let me know.

Comment: Code samples should be included on Stackoverflow. There are dead links in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 13 has an error. The `>` should be prefix:

```
(if (and (palindrome? currVal) (> currVal targetP))
```

The error message is telling you that a Long could not be cast to a function. (i.e. currVal is not a function)

Comment: Anytime! In terms of cleaning up your code, I'd recommend avoiding defs (learn let, et.al. instead). Also, probably want to start with the high numbers rather than the low. That way, your first result is your answer. Finally, if you haven't tried it, check out http://www.4clojure.com/. It will get you into the clojure mindset.